# format output from asMinutes method in momentJs

Tags: momentjs

This operation

```
moment.duration(3611635).asMinutes()
```

returns `60.19391666666667`

Can I format with momentJs lib to get rounded number or less decimal places?

Comment: Any reason not to use `Math.round()`?

Comment: Just asking if I can pass a parameter to format output. Will use `Math.round()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:**
if you want to use moment, you will have to first convert to hours and then to minutes:

```
moment.duration(3917000).hours() * 60 + moment.duration(3917000).minutes()
```

**original post:**

You can use the Javascript function for [round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```
Math.round(x)
```

if you want to always round down you can use [floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

```
Math.floor(x)
```

and if you want to always round up you can use [ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

```
Math.ceil(x)
```